# Adding a property to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, frontend, velo

I have an array of objects as shown below

```
Array(2)
0: "104635ac-4b9a-3f7a-d4f8-e8badca83d58"
1: "547d57b7-ddc7-a481-95e4-ccfe2a6404a8"
```

I want to add two more properties one named productId and one name quantity to each element of this array of Objects.

The final outcome should be as follows.

```
  {
    "productId": "104635ac-4b9a-3f7a-d4f8-e8badca83d58",
    "quantity": 1,
  },
  {
    "productId": "547d57b7-ddc7-a481-95e4-ccfe2a6404a8",
    "quantity": 1,
  }
```

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate targets found by Googling _“site:stackoverflow.com js convert array of strings to array of objects”_.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.map` to map through the array and construct an object:

```js
const arr = ["104635ac-4b9a-3f7a-d4f8-e8badca83d58","547d57b7-ddc7-a481-95e4-ccfe2a6404a8"]

const result = arr.map(e => ({quantity: 1, productId: e}))

console.log(result)
```